# How to create a custom BuiltinParameterGroup in revit api c#

Tags: c#, revit-api

I am working on a revit api project where I am asked to create a custom Category for some group of shared parameters.

initially, I had used was this "PG_IDENTITY_DATA"

```
doc.ParameterBindings.Insert(definition, binding, BuiltInParameterGroup.PG_IDENTITY_DATA);
```

But, after the above requirement, I used "BuiltInParameterGroup.PG_DATA" and "BuiltInParameterGroup.INVALID", but it created categories like "Data" and "Other" respectively.

So I wanted help to understand whether creating Custom Group for parameters is possible, if yes, please guide me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason the thing You are trying to change is a BuiltInParameterGroup.
You cannot add new or change existing its a built in enum.

There are some answers already in Autodesk forums you can read but they will all give You the same solution.

[Here as an Example](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/parameter-group-creation/td-p/9906807)

Generally speaking there are multiple groups you can assign to list available here

[API Doc](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/9942b791-2892-0658-303e-abf99675c5a6.htm)

And here a forum answer as to which ones are user assignable

[Autodesk Forums](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/builtinparametergroup-how-to-get-only-values-shown-in-ui/td-p/6277765)

Hope that helps.